# "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" using a static library in iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, ios-4.2

I'm trying to create a static library in xcode 4.2.

I'm following the steps in [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/) tutorial. However, I get the following error:

```
Ld /Users/harishk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testlib-ailufzhcoulmzrflyhfgbwqbiksx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Testlib.app/Testlib normal i386
    cd /Users/harishk/Desktop/sl/Testlib
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/harishk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testlib-ailufzhcoulmzrflyhfgbwqbiksx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/harishk/Desktop/sl/Testlib/Testlib/lib -L/Users/harishk/Desktop/sl/Testlib/../lib -L/Users/harishk/Desktop/sl/Testlib -F/Users/harishk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testlib-ailufzhcoulmzrflyhfgbwqbiksx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/harishk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testlib-ailufzhcoulmzrflyhfgbwqbiksx/Build/Intermediates/Testlib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Testlib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Testlib.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -objC -all_load -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lSimpleLibrary -o /Users/harishk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testlib-ailufzhcoulmzrflyhfgbwqbiksx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Testlib.app/Testlib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/harishk/Desktop/sl/lib/libSimpleLibrary.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MathFunctions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you trying to create the library or trying to use the created library in an application?

Answer (score 1):

The `MathFunctions` class is missing. Either from your application project or from the `SimpleLibrary.a` that you use. Make sure it is part of the compilation and linking steps of your build.